# WiX - install windows service to run in x64 mode

Tags: .net, installation, wix, wix3.5

I'm installing a Windows Service using WiX 3.5 and its ServiceInstall tag:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="WindowsServiceContentDir">
        <Component Id="WindowsServiceExecutableComponent" Guid="*" Win64="yes">
            <File Source="$(var.WindowsServiceTargetDir)$(var.WindowsServiceTargetName).exe" KeyPath="yes" />

            <ServiceInstall Id="WindowsServiceInstall" Type="ownProcess" Start="auto" ErrorControl="normal" Vital="yes"
                            Name="[WIN_SERVICE_NAME]" DisplayName="Name"
                            Description="Name"
                            Account="[DENTITY_DOMAIN]\[IDENTITY_NAME]"
                            Password="[IDENTITY_PWD]">
            </ServiceInstall>


            <ServiceControl Id="WindowsServiceStop" Name="[WIN_SERVICE_NAME]" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
        </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

After installation on 64bit machine, the service is running in 32bit (x86) mode, despite the Win64="yes" attribute. What else need to be done to run service in x64 mode after installation?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type="ownProcess" in service install is for win32 process hence the service is running in 32bit mode. Maybe you can use custom actions to install the service instead of ServiceInstall element.